# How in Matlab to create matrix representing exponential averaging system?

Tags: matlab, matrix, exponential

Denote `w(n)` to be `(1 - a)^n`

I would like to create a following `NxN` matrix:

```
// Note that 1 = w(0)
1       0       0  ...  0       0
w(1)    1       0  ...  0       0
w(2)    w(1)    1  ...  0       0
.................................
w(n-1)  w(n-2)  ...     w(1)    1
```

**Question**: what's a short way to do that in Matlab for the case `a = 1/2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
r = (1-a).^(0:N-1)
out = tril(bsxfun(@rdivide,r.',r))
```

Sample run -

```
>> a = 1/2;
>> N = 5;
>> r = (1-a).^(0:N-1);
>> tril(bsxfun(@rdivide,r.',r))
ans =
            1            0            0            0            0
          0.5            1            0            0            0
         0.25          0.5            1            0            0
        0.125         0.25          0.5            1            0
       0.0625        0.125         0.25          0.5            1
```

On MATLAB 2016b version onwards with automatic broadcasting, the last step  would be -

```
out = tril(r.'./r)
```